# In ZF2 where i have to declare common arrays (Countries , cities , pincode , etc ... )

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Kindly tell me In ZF2 where i have  to declare common arrays (Countries , cities , pincode , etc  ... )

In **autoload/local.php**, **autoload/global.php**, or **autoload/commonarrays.global.php**?

and I need to access those arrays from all of my modules' `Model` class and `Controller` class.

**FYI**

I declared arrays in **autoload/local.php** by using `ServiceManager` I can access common arrays in `Controller` class, but I need to access that common arrays in

```
E:\...\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Member\src\Member\Form\SignupForm.php
```

To show a select box for `countries`. I can't create an instance of `ServiceManager` in **SignupForm.php**.

What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa !,  I did it , ......

I did these changes :

In my **module.php**

Method

```
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
            // some code goes here //
            // some code goes here //

                /**       I added these lines         **/
                'Member\Form\SignupForm' =>  function($sm) {
                    $SignupForm = new SignupForm($sm);
                    return $SignupForm;
                },
                /**      I added these lines         **/
            ),
        );
    }
```

In **\module\Member\src\Member\Form\SignupForm.php**

```
    class SignupForm extends Form 
    {
    /**              I added these lines         **/
        protected $serviceManager;

        public function __construct($serviceManager)
        {


            $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;

            print_r($this->serviceManager->get('Config'));  
        /**              I added these lines         **/    
            // some code goes here //
        }   
            // some code goes here //

    }
```

In **\module\Member\src\Member\Controller\MemberController.php**

```
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Member\Form\SignupForm');
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make a lot of sense to create classes for those and use Dependency Injection for injecting into controllers / models / view helpers. You can inject into your controllers and view helpers in Module.php

Reason to wrap your arrays in classes: at the moment you might have hard-coded arrays, but what if in the future you will store those in a file/database/memcached.

This article on DI will be very helpful:

http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/07/getting-dependencies-into-zf2-controllers/

Comment: Actually i can access config arrays in controllers , i need to access those in model file. I need exactly [this](https://gist.github.com/gpeltink/3499563). (i.e) I need an instance of servicemanager in model class, then i can get common arrays from that

Comment: @user2432106 While you're right about DI, it's overkill for this situation in my opinion.  Like the old adage goes, "there is something to be said about just _getting the job done_."  Also, perhaps this should have been a comment since it's a suggestion that A. does not answer the question and B. isn't even fully explained with examples or something.  Still, kudos on being right as far as methodology goes.